# Build project with h323plus lib, using Qt

Tags: c++, qt, build, voip

I built h323plus and PWLib using msvc 2008. Then I built samples and it works fine, but now I need to use this libs with Qt.
Using msvc I'm adding include directories, lib directories and also libs which I want to add to project. It is enough to make work the following code:

```
#include <ptlib.h>
#include <h323.h>

class SimpleClass : public PProcess
{
    PCLASSINFO(SimpleClass, PProcess)
public:

    void Main()
    {
        std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
    }
};

PCREATE_PROCESS(SimpleClass)
```

I'm trying to do same actions using Qt (MinGW).
I added INCLUDEPATH and LIBS to .pro file.
It seems it included correctly. But I have a lot of errors:

C:\Qt\projetcs\test1\main.cpp:16: error: undefined reference to `PProcess::PreInitialise(int, char**, char**)'

I believe the header was found and successfully included, but I don't understand why PProccess functions were not founded.
It's maybe need to define some flags or have special config for compiler.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What this macro 'PCREATE_PROCESS' defines?

Comment: `#else
#define PCREATE_PROCESS(cls) \
  int main(int argc, char ** argv, char ** envp) \
    { \
      cls *pInstance = new cls(); \
      pInstance->PreInitialise(argc, argv, envp); \
      int terminationValue = pInstance->InternalMain(); \
      delete pInstance; \
      return terminationValue; \
    }
#endif`

Comment: Thanks. Compiler complains about missing PreInitilise() function in your SimpleClass. Is it inherited from PProcess? Does PProcess have such function: `PreInitialise(int, char*, char*)`?

Comment: >>Does PProcess have such function?
yes.
As I told above, this code is correct for msvc 2008

Comment: Than probably msvc defines something that Qt pro file is missing. Did you compare preprocessor definitions?

Comment: How can I find msvc definitions?

Comment: If you have MSVC project, open its property page in VisualStudio IDE. You can find preprocessor definitions under `Configureation Properties->C/C++->Preprocessor` page.

Comment: if my understanding correct, following constants defined
WIN32;_DEBUG;_CONSOLE
But problem remains even if I define this constants in Qt